# In application I have acsess to JDBC driver (exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver)

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, intellij-idea, jdbc

The same project *servlet* application does not work, but "hello world" method, in the **same** project, yes.
 Here the picture ofproject.

[image]

**Versions:**

*Intellij IDEA* - **2018.2**

*mySQL* driver version: ***8.0.11***, driver ***com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver***

*servlet* **9.0.81**

**In Code:**

```
Class.forName(dbDriver).newInstance();
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, password);
```

**Exception:**

*java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver*
...

**BTW:**

The same exception I receive also without *mysql* dependency in *PON.xml*

So, this is issue or I missing something. 
Thanks

**UPDATE**
[image]

**SOLVED:** We need to **add library in Artifact**.

Comment: @JoopEggen In Web Applications when the driver is deployed in the war, `Class.forName` is still very much necessary. `DriverManager` only automatically loads drivers from the initial (system) classpath, not from context classpaths. However, this is usually avoided by using data sources instead of (directly) using `DriverManager`. Either the data source has direct access to the driver, or its configuration forces you to specify the driver class name anyway.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes, I am doing too much desktop programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure all the required jars are also included in the [Artifact configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) that you are deploying on the application server.

Comment: Thank you, but from  "hello world" application  from the same project which works .normally. But in the Servlet application not.

Comment: Yes, module dependencies may be not included into the artifact automatically, check what libraries are deployed with the servlet.

Comment: Isn't this enough? (added photo of Artifacts)

Comment: Artifacts image clearly shows that you didn't add the libraries to `WEB-INF\lib` directory of the artifact since they are shown in the Available Elements. Available means that these are the libraries that are not yet added to the artifact.

Comment: Thank you, it now works, but I thinked that  after added in POM is enough.

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan It depends on whether you use Maven to generate the WAR or not. It looks like you use IntelliJ to generate the WAR, not Maven.

Comment: @MarkRottevee I do the following step to web project:
l File->New->Project->select Maven->right  click->Add Framework Support->Then select "Web App..."->then add in POM.xml add dependencies which use and after that I will "manually" add these jars in Artifacts

Comment: Yes, but the screenshot shows you are not using Maven to generate the WAR, you are using IntelliJ's internal feature to do that instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel it's not that simple. When Maven web project is imported in IntelliJ IDEA, it will generate artifacts with all the dependencies automatically, but if the artifact was created manually or dependencies were updated later, the new dependencies will not be included in the already existing artifact.

Comment: @CrazyCoder You can also let IntelliJ use Maven to generate the WAR, then you don't need to define or update the WAR definition yourself.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sure you can, but hot deployment/update will not work when debugging the application built by Maven (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html).

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks, learnt something new, I usually don't use hot-deploy things, because somehow they never work quite right for me.